# Match by location and attribute in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, spatial-join, query

I have 2 different layers.  One layer is the field layer which contains field agronomic data, name, variety, etc.  The other layer is a layer with about 2000 polygons. Each polygon is tied to a variety.  Some contain the same variety and are in different locations.  Also there are some areas that have polygons stacked on top of each other that contain different varieties.

I want to determine if there are any fields inside a polygon that contain the variety inside the polygon.  Another way of saying, I want to know if there are any fields inside the different polygons that have that variety.

[image: The large polygons have one variety as an attribute. The small polygons are the fields. The fields contain agronomic information. I want to know if any of theses smaller fields contain]

I have tried join by location.  (1:Many)Instead of telling me which polygons contain the field, I only get back how many polygons as a count.  since I am not getting the information from the polygon layer, I cannot query if the varieties match.

I have also tried joining by attribute.  Doing this will link up the varieties, but it is not spatially accurate.

I am using QGIS.

Answer (score 2):

A Virtual Layer should do the trick (Layer|Create Layer|New Virual Layer)
If your field layer was named `Fields` and contained the columns `Field_Name` and `variety`
and the other polygon layer was named `Regions` and contained the columns `Region_Name` and `variety` then the SQL for the Query would be:

```
SELECT F.Field_Name, F.variety, R.Region_Name, F.geometry
FROM Fields F 
JOIN Regions R ON F.variety=R.variety AND ST_WITHIN(F.geometry,R.geometry)
```

This will create a query layer containing only the fields which are within polygons of the same variety.